# What's the point of being lucky?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

In Binding of Isaac: Rebirth, luck has been made a visible stat. (It was present in the original game, but not shown on the stat screen, unless I just *totally* missed it). However, even with 2 or 3 points of luck, I still find myself gulping down random pills which have a negative effect such as stat downs. (This could of course be confirmation bias). I've also not noticed much other impact of being lucky.

So if being lucky doesn't seem to impact things like pills and the stuff I get from beggars etc., what's it good for? There are items which specifically increase your luck such as the Lucky Foot, so it must do *something*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Gamepedia BoI:Rebirth wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Attributes#Luck), luck will:

- Increase the chance of drops after clearing a room.
- Increase the chance of random tear effects (teeth, poison, fear, infatuation, slow,..) happening.
- Increase the payout rate of slot machine and shell game

Some random oriented things luck does not have an effect on:

- Luck does *not* increase the payout rate of other beggars (coin/heart/key)
- Luck does *not* affect the fortune teller or portable slots.
- Luck does *not* change the contents of chests, other objects that spawn drops (mushrooms, skulls, etc), angel/devil rooms
- Luck does *not* increase the trigger chance of Gimpy, Fanny Pack, Dry Baby, Mulligan, Broken Watch, Infamy, or Guppy's Collar.

Comment: It should affects the chance of NOT having a curse on the floor, and I'm pretty sure it increases the chance of finding better pills, too.

Comment: If it does increase the chance for better pills, it does so nearly imperceptibly. At least compared to the original game where the Luck Foot was as good as the PHD. If you have a credible source that can prove lucks relation to pill quality, feel free to link to it or provide your own answer.

Comment: I have no source at the moment, I'm just considering the effects of the [Lucky Foot](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Lucky_Foot) and what I've seen in my gameplays.

Comment: From what I understand, the types of pills that are available in a specific run are predetermined as soon as the run starts, so luck does not affect which ones you get. The only time the "pill pool" changes is when you pick up an item like PHD or Virgo.